# Render epub files in android

Tags: android, webview, epub

I have a epub file. I need to unzip and parse the epub file and render it in Webview. Is there a step by step tutorial somewhere.

Comment: Start with this lib for reading epubs: https://github.com/psiegman/epublib

Answer (score 25):

1. Visit [this site](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) and download the two jar files mentioned in that page.
2. Import those libraries to your android project
3. I implemented this task using two activities :
     1.) EpubReaderActivity - this activity will display a list view of Table of Contents
     2.) ContentViewActivity - this will display the selected chapter.

**EpubReaderActivity.java**

```
public class EpubReaderActivity extends ListActivity 
{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<RowData> contentDetails;
public static final String BOOK_NAME = "books/wodehouse.epub";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    contentDetails = new ArrayList<RowData>();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager.open(BOOK_NAME);
        Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
        logContentsTable(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,
            R.id.title, contentDetails);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData>{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        private View row;
        private TextView titleHolder = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            super();
            this.row = row;
        }

        public TextView getTitle() {
            if(null == titleHolder)
                titleHolder = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            return titleHolder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        RowData rowData = getItem(position);
        if(null == convertView){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        title = holder.getTitle();
        title.setText(rowData.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

}

private void logContentsTable(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (TOCReference tocReference:tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }
        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.setTitle(tocString.toString());
        row.setResource(tocReference.getResource());
        contentDetails.add(row);
        logContentsTable(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
}

private class RowData{
    private String title;
    private Resource resource;

    public RowData() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

}



@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    RowData rowData = contentDetails.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MicroEpubReaderActivity.this, ContentViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("display", new String(rowData.getResource().getData()));
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

---

**ContentViewActivity.java**

```
public class ContentViewActivity extends Activity {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String displayString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("display");
    if(displayString != null)
        webView.loadData(displayString, "text/html", "utf-8");
}   
}
```

Comment: Hi
could you send main.xml file, please?

Comment: No GAMA, I didn't get it. If you receive tell me, please.

Comment: @omidnazifi, I used PageTurner https://github.com/nightwhistler/pageturner ... it's working...

Comment: clicked on any logContentsTable take up to same place , not the correct location

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ListActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

main.xml
Use this with pkamalaruban's answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use stage web view for rendering epub simply pass the epub directly....The android native web kit browser supports almost all formats for rendering.

```
var stageWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView;
stageWebView.stage = stage;  
stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight-100);  
stageWebView.loadURL("http://localhost/eboard.pdf"); // use any path
```

You dont require any zip/unzip or parsing....but in case you do not go for web view then you might need that...

Comment: Need it for epub and not pdf.

Comment: StageWebView is an Adobe thing and is not the same as Android's WebView.