# Working with ePub files in android

Tags: android, android-webview, epub

I referred this [siegmann android tutorial](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android)
and successfully logged the `Title`, `Author name` and `Table of contents`.

Now I read that the whole book can be viewed in `WebView`.

But I don't find any tutorial for *Dispalying an ePub file*.

When it comes to creating an ePub file, I found [this from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640728/render-epub-files-in-android)
But I'm unable to implement it as I don't have any idea about `main.xml`.

Kindly suggest any tutorial to **create and display an ePub file.**

For creating ePub, I tried to refer [this siegmann eg](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/example-programs/epub-sample-simple1)
but I'm not able to understand it properly.

Do I need to provide `.html` for each chapter and `.css` in order to create an ePub file?

I know I'm little unclear in this qustion as I'm absolute beginner when it comes to working with ePub, so any suggestions/help appreciated.

Comment: follow this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313113/taking-long-time-to-display-epub-files-in-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `logTableOfContents()`

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {

line1 = line1.concat(Html.fromHtml(line).toString());

}

finalstr = finalstr.concat("\n").concat(line1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also spine the epub content with the help of

```
        Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
        List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
        int count = spineList.size();
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
            Resource res = spine.getResource(i);
            try {
                InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                        System.err.println("res media"+res.getMediaType());
                        htmlTextStr = Html.fromHtml(linez).toString();
                        Log.e("Html content.",htmlTextStr);
                        speak(htmlTextStr);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                //do something with stream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", linez, "application/xhtml+xml", "UTF-8", null);
```